# Syntax error -unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)

Tags: php

I keep getting this Syntax error- (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)) but can't find where I forgot to put @endif. I'm still pretty new with php so it could be something pretty obvious too.
I would be very grateful if someone with the fresh eye could see it and help me.
Thanks

````
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-5">
            <div class="col-lg-3 d-none d-sm-block">
                @include('includes.sidebar', ['user'=> Auth::user()])
                @include('includes.messages')
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <a href="{{ route('chats') }}" class="btn btn-link float-right">Povratak na sve poruke</a>
                <h3><a href="{{ route('reviews', ['id' => $receiver->id]) }}">{{ $receiver->name }}</a></h3>
                <div class="media my-3">
                    @if($parent->sender_id != Auth::user()->id && Helper::instance()->getUser($parent->sender_id)->image)
                        <a href="{{ route('reviews', ['id' => $parent->sender_id]) }}">
                            <img class="img-comment mr-3 rounded-circle lazy" data-src="{{ Helper::instance()->getUser($parent->sender_id)->image }}" alt="{{ Helper::instance()->getUser($parent->sender_id)->name }}">
                        </a>
                    @elseif($parent->receiver_id != Auth::user()->id && Helper::instance()->getUser($parent->receiver_id)->image)
                        <a href="{{ route('reviews', ['id' => $parent->receiver_id]) }}">
                            <img class="img-comment mr-3 rounded-circle lazy" data-src="{{ Helper::instance()->getUser($parent->receiver_id)->image }}" alt="{{ Helper::instance()->getUser($parent->receiver_id)->name }}">
                        </a>
                    @else
                        <i class="fas fa-user-circle text-muted mr-3 image-default"></i>
                    @endif
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <small class="text-muted float-right">
                            <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{ Helper::instance()->getMessageDate($parent) }}
                        </small>
                        <h4>{{ $parent->subject }}</h4>
                        <p>{!! nl2br(e($parent->message)) !!}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                @if($messages->isNotEmpty())
                    <div id="chat-container">
                        @foreach($messages as $message)
                            <div class="media my-1">
                                @if(Auth::user()->id != $message->receiver_id)
                                    <div class="media-body text-right">
                                        <p>{!! nl2br(e($message->message)) !!}</p>
                                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{ $message->created_at->timezone('America/Mexico_City')->format('H:i:s d/m/Y') }}</small>
                                    </div>
                                    @if(Helper::instance()->getUser($message->sender_id)->image)
                                        <img class="img-comment ml-3 rounded-circle lazy" data-src="{{ Helper::instance()->getUser($message->sender_id)->image }}" alt="{{ Helper::instance()->getUser($message->sender_id)->name }}">
                                    @else
                                        <i class="fas fa-user-circle text-muted mr-3 image-default"></i>
                                    @endif
                                @else
                                    @if(Helper::instance()->getUser($message->sender_id)->image)
                                        <img class="img-comment mr-3 rounded-circle lazy" data-src="{{ Helper::instance()->getUser($message->sender_id)->image }}" alt="{{ Helper::instance()->getUser($message->sender_id)->name }}">
                                    @else
                                        <i class="fas fa-user-circle text-muted mr-3 image-default"></i>
                                    @endif
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <p>{!! nl2br(e($message->message)) !!}</p>
                                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{ $message->created_at->timezone('America/Mexico_City')->format('H:i:s d/m/Y') }}</small>
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                @endif
                <hr class="mt-5">
                <form action="{{ route('send-message') }}" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <label for="message" class="sr-only">Poruka *</label>
                                <textarea id="message" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Vaša poruka" minlength="2" maxlength="1000" rows="5">@if(isset($product))Pozdrav, </textarea>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="{{ $parent->id }}">
                            <div class="col-lg-2 mt-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Poslati</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('js')
    <script>
        $('.toast').toast('show');

        /*var chat = document.getElementById('chat-container');
        chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight - chat.clientHeight;*/
        $("#chat-container").scrollTop(400);
    </script>
@endsection```
````

Comment: `@if(isset($product))Pozdrav,` (in the message textarea) isn't getting closed.

Comment: Yes, that was the error! Thank you very much Magnus.